# When Debugging in Xcode what does "out of scope" mean?

Tags: iphone, debugging, properties

I'm in xcode debugging my iphone application.  when i get to a break point and I roll over my object and properties of that object say "out of scope" instead of their respective values.

Here's what I do:

I have inited a view with nib name (initwithnibname).

Then set the property of that view to the object that I want.

I have placed the breakpoint in the viewwillappear method.

I rollover my reference to the variable that was is my property.

All properties in the object say "out of scope"

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: I haven't worked with Xcode yet, but I would assume it means you're attempting to reference the object outside of the scope the variable was declared in....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not used XCode either, but it sounds like you're using a variable that is not in scope - say referring to a local variable in a method from another method etc...

Find where the variable is declared - that should give you a big clue...

Comment: Also, if you declare something inside a if statement, or loop of some kind, then outside that loop, you won't be able to use or see it.

Answer (score 0):

These are released objects.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you "set the property of the view to the object that I want".

Could you clarify on this, did you mean you set the nib file File's Owner to your View Controller class?

What specific errors did you receive in the console?